# Finding middle point for consecutive number

Tags: matlab

Let say I have

```
A=[1 3 4 5 6 7 9 12 15 16 17 18 20 23 24 25 26];
```

My interest is how to find the middle value between consecutive numbers using Matlab.

For example, first group of consecutive numbers is

```
B=[3 4 5 6 7];
```

so the answer should be is `5`. The 2nd group of consecutive numbers (i.e. `[15 16 17 18]`) should give `16` etc...

At the end, my final answer is

```
[5 16 24]
```

Comment: how come in the 2nd example the middle number is not 17? Do you round to the lower integer? In any case it looks like you're looking for the median value is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I looking for median value. How to get it. Accually, I have diff (A). The result, I get is [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]; then I stuck. I dont know how to find a median point in consecutive number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized approach:

```
d = [diff(A) == 1, 0];
subs = cumsum([diff(d) == 1, 0]).*(d | [0, diff(d) == -1]) + 1
temp = accumarray(subs', A', [], @median)
final = floor(temp(2:end))
```

Comment: @danjoro If this has solved your problem (or any of the other answers) then please consider [marking it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code which does what you are looking for. I'll let you play with the different outputs to see what they do exactly, although I wrote some comments to follow:

```
clear
clc

A=[1 3 4 5 6 7 9 12 15 16 17 18 20 23 24 25 26]

a=diff(A); %// Check the diff array to identify occurences different than 1.

b=find([a inf]>1);
NumElements=diff([0 b]); %//Number of elements in the sequence

LengthConsec = NumElements((NumElements~=1)) %// Get sequences with >1 values
EndConsec = b(NumElements~=1) %// Check end values to deduce starting values
StartConsec = EndConsec-LengthConsec+1;

%// Initialize a cell array containing the sequences (can have ifferent
%lengths, i.e. an array is not recommended) and an array containing the
%median values.
ConsecCell = cell(1,numel(LengthConsec));
MedianValue = zeros(1,numel(LengthConsec));

for k = 1:numel(LengthConsec)

    ConsecCell{1,k} = A(StartConsec(k):1:EndConsec(k));
    MedianValue(k) = floor(median(ConsecCell{1,k}));
end

%//Display the result
MedianValue
```

Giving the following:

```
MedianValue =

     5    16    24
```

Answer (score 1):

`diff + strfind` based approach -

```
loc_consec_nums = diff(A)==1 %// locations of consecutive (cons.) numbers
starts = strfind([0 loc_consec_nums],[0 1]) %// start indices of cons. numbers
ends = strfind([loc_consec_nums 0],[1 0]) %// end indices of cons. numbers
out = A(ceil(sum([starts ; ends],1)./2))%// median of each group of starts and ends
              %// and finally index into A with them for the desired output
```